# Selecting columns base on names in Azure Data Factory's dataflow activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have some columns in my dataset that I want to map. I want to select all these columns to map to my sink dataset except for the column named 'Total People'

I know I need to use the select activity but what I've done results in only the Total People column being mapped. How do I fix this such that every other column is mapped except the 'Total People' column
[Input columns mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFXbA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Rule based mapping in the select transformation.

This is my sample data.

[image]

Give the condition `name!='Total People'` in the Rule based mapping like below.

[image]

**Result with removed column:**

[image]